# using selenium / firefox webdriver / after click() / code waits forever even after popup window is generated

Tags: python, selenium, popup, click, webdriver

Below is the code that I am testing.
I'm trying to download the source codes from samsung's webpage but some how the codes get stuck when click() is executed. The popup appears but doesn't proceed to the next code in the program. If I close the code manully, then the program executes the next line. I think the program is waiting for some feedback from the popup.

How can I make it proceed to the next line? How should I solve this problem?

any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

dr.get('http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=list&menu_item=mobile&classification1=mobile_phone&classification2=&classification3=')

lefts = dr.find_elements_by_class_name("left")

print "number of lefts", len(lefts)

i = 0

cnt = 1

chandle = dr.current_window_handle

for left in lefts:
try:

    left.click()

except:

    print "click fail"

for h in dr.window_handles:

    print h, dr.current_window_handle

if chandle != h:

        dr.switch_to_window(h)

i=i+1

if i == cnt:

    break
```

Comment: The elements returned by `lefts = dr.find_elements_by_class_name("left")` need not have any action when being clicked on. I recommend checking the first element returned on firebug when you search for that class name. My bet is its not what you expect.

Comment: if I run the code the popup actually pops up. I think it works because it has a onclick() event handler. But it stops from there..

Comment: So you are saying the click works? So whats the problem? Are you not able to switch control to the popup?

Comment: The popup appears but the program is still stuck at left.click(). I think the function might be waiting for some kind of response/feedback. I'm not sure... I just started working with selenium yesterday. This similar code works for other websites, but not for the samsung one. hmm.. I'm still trying to figure out the solution.

Comment: you need to wait for `for h in dr.window_handles:

    print h, dr.current_window_handle` , so wait for length of window_handle to increase

Comment: I actually tried printing text for debugging before 'for h in dr.window_handles:'. Just added simple code like 'print "after print'. But the text wasn't actually printed. Which means that for some reason the program is stuck at 'left.click()' after making the popup. Once I close the popup manually the code proceeds to the next line. I think the program is waiting for something but don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Clicks are blocking actions, in that WebDriver is waiting for the Click to return once that page is loaded, and with the popup, it's not returning.

To get around this, try running the click in a separate thread.  Even though it will block, it will then not block the rest of your program from executing.  Once you are done with the popup, have your main program close the popup, which will unblock the click running on its own thread.